# Choose where to spawn a command in Yeoman

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator, spawn, cd

I'm building a generator and I need at the end to `npm install` in a certain directory in my app, I tried things like:

```
this.spawnCommandSync('cd', [this.destinationRoot() + '/my/folder'])
this.spawnCommandSync('npm', ['install'])
```

but it doesn't work.

And `npm install` can't be called in a different directory nor any of the [yeoman install mixins](http://yeoman.io/generator/actions_install.html#.installDependencies).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass the option `cwd` - just like https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options